# How to accelerate massive SKNode actions?

Tags: ios, image-processing, sprite-kit, gpu, metal

iOS SpriteKit API is easy to use. However, if I run massive actions (about 5000+) on a lot of SKSpriteNode (about 2000+) at the same time, the fps drops very low. But the GPU usage in this situation is far less than CPU usage. Is there any method to accelerate actions on GPU? Or is there any way to implement images with moving, scaling, fading and rotating actions under MetalKit?

Comment: Yes Metalkit should give you ability to fine tune your computations.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès So how can I integrate SpriteKit Actions with MetalKit?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can't...

Comment: Metalkit is designed for GPU, not CPU.  No you cannot move your actions from CPU to GPU. You need to evaluate your code. Ask yourself, why are you running 5000 actions? Also, why do you have 2000 nodes on the screen?  What can you do to optimize this and reduce your numbers

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I agree... However it is not possible to reduce the number of actions. I will ignore this problem because it doesn't usually happen. In the future maybe I can try to implement these actions under Metal or OpenglES.

Comment: That is a terrible route to go, most of what you are doing is already being handled on the GPU for the parts that need to be done by the GPU.  If your have something that can be done solely on the GPU, then it should not be an action.  E.G. In an instance where you need to immediately rotate a sprite, you do not use actions. As for this "However it is not possible to reduce the number of actions"  I am calling you out for being lazy if you accept that, I bet you if you showed what those 5000 actions are to people, they will explain how to reduce them.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Okay... I can tell you that I am trying to implement [osu! Storyboard](https://osu.ppy.sh/wiki/Storyboard_Scripting_General_Rules) on iOS. The original player is designed for PC, so it is normal that 5000+ actions run at the same time. However, SpriteKit seems to run Actions on CPU instead of GPU, hence the performance is not enough to handle so many actions at the same time.

Comment: You are porting a PC app to iOS you are going to have to make sacrifices.  Perhaps you should attempt to do it in Unity instead of Sprite Kit since Unity has better handling of grouping actions and optimizing them.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for your advice. I think I should learn more about game engines and finally decide how to solve this problem.

Comment: yeah,  I am not sure if you are working with the actual code, or just trying to translate the scripts into something that iOS can read, I do not know too much about this program

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Actually I am writing code to decode these commands. The code is available on [github](https://github.com/imxieyi/iosu).

Answer (score 0):

You can use shaders on nodes to change their appearance. This would be beneficial for moving, scaling, fading and rotating nodes. I would normally suggest using SKActions for these since they are very basic functions that the CPU would normally handle instead of the GPU, and in your case I would recommend that you review why you need to make changes to some 2000 nodes at one time.

Whenever you have that many nodes, you can likely replace them with an SKEmitterNode. It's much harder to use PhysicsBodies with the individual emissions, but they are much more resource friendly than using an individual 5000 nodes.